# Is a struct's address the same as its first member's address?

Tags: c++, pointers, websocket, structure, ace

Consider I have Struct like the following:

```
struct Bitmask
{
  unsigned char payload_length: 7;
  unsigned char mask: 1;
  unsigned char opcode: 4;
  unsigned char rsv3: 1;
  unsigned char rsv2: 1;
  unsigned char rsv1: 1;
  unsigned char fin: 1;
};

const char* payload = "Hello";
const size_t payload_length = strlen(payload);

Bitmask* header = new Bitmask();
header->fin =1;
header->rsv1 = 0;
header->rsv2 = 0;
header->rsv3 = 0;
header->opcode = 1;
header->mask = 0;
header->payload_length = payload_length;

iovec iov[2];
iov[0].iov_base = (char*)header;
iov[0].iov_len = sizeof (header);
iov[1].iov_base = (char *)payload;
iov[1].iov_len = strlen(payload);

ACE_DEBUG ((LM_DEBUG,
            ACE_TEXT ("iov[0].length = %d\niov[1].length = %d\n"),
            iov[0].iov_len,
            iov[1].iov_len));

size_t bytes_xfered;
client_stream_.sendv_n (iov, 2, 0, &bytes_xfered);

cout << "Transfered " << bytes_xfered << " byte(s)" << std::endl;
```

I am initializing it with appropriate values. Finally, I want to convert the struct into char* so I can append my payload (which is char* message) and send it over a websocket connection.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is a struct's address the same as its first member's address?

Yes, this is actually mandated by the C and C++ standards. From the C standard:

> 6.7.2.1-13. A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member

The size of your `struct` should be two bytes. You should not convert a pointer to it to `char*`, though: instead, you should use [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/) to copy your `Bitmask` into the buffer that you send over the network.

**EDIT** Since you use scatter-gather I/O with `iovec`, you do not need to cast `Bitmask` to anything: `iov_base` is `void*`, so you can simply set `iov[0].iov_base = header;`

Note: This works only as long as your `struct` does not contain virtual functions, base classes, etc. (thanks, Timo).

**EDIT2**

In order to get {0x81, 0x05} in your `struct`, you should change the order of structure elements as follows:

```
struct Bitmask {
    unsigned char opcode: 4; 
    unsigned char rsv3: 1; 
    unsigned char rsv2: 1; 
    unsigned char rsv1: 1; 
    unsigned char fin: 1; 
    unsigned char payload_length: 7; 
    unsigned char mask: 1;
}
```

Comment: In c++ this only holds true for POD structs.

Comment: Do I need to copy Bitmask member by member or following will do:

char header_[2];
memcpy(header_,bitmask,2);

Comment: @DarshanPuranik I did not realize that you were using scatter-gather I/O. See my edit.

Comment: iov[0].iov_base is char*. 'iov[0].iov_base = header;' then i get compile error c2440.

Comment: @DarshanPuranik `{0x81, 0x05}` is not what gets written in the bits of `Bitmask` the way you specified. The data in the two bytes of `Bitmask` is `{0x11, 0x0A}`. With bit fields the bits are allocated lower-to-higher, hence the top bit is `0x01`, second from the top bit is `0x02`, and so on.

Comment: @DarshanPuranik ...error c2440. This is strange: [opengroup says that it needs to be void*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/sys/uio.h.html).

Comment: I am using ACE. http://www.aoc.nrao.edu/php/tjuerges/ALMA/ACE-5.5.2/html/ace/structiovec.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7598/discussion-between-darshan-puranik-and-dasblinkenlight)

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

In general, this is true (as dasblinkenlight explains), but it specifically doesn't hold for bitfields. Per C++11 9.6/3 "there are no pointers to bitfields" so they don't have addresses, either. And obviously, "A pointer to a structure object, *suitably converted*, points to its initial member" breaks down if there is no "suitable conversion".

Answer (score 1):

The address of a structure is the same as the address of its first member, provided that the appropriate cast is used. Given the below declaration of `struct my_struct`, if `item` is of type struct

```
my_struct, then (char *)item == &item.wp_cval.


struct my_struct
{

      char wp_cval;
      short wp_font;
      short wp_psize;


}ar[ARSIZE];
```