# Getting a Pointer to the First Element of a Struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, alignment, member

I thought that the standard provided me a function to find the 1<sup>st</sup> element of a struct. I can't seem to find that though.

I'm scared of alignment: I don't think it's legal to `reinterpret_cast` into the 1<sup>st</sup> element of a struct is it?

So for example given `struct { int first, int second } foo`; how would I get the address of the 1<sup>st</sup> element in `foo`, if I didn't know that `first` is laid out as the 1<sup>st</sup> element? (Meaning that `&foo.first` is not a valid solution.)

Comment: Looks like maybe you are looking for [`std::offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof).  I'll try and find a dupe if that is the case

Comment: Otherwise the address of the struct and the address of the first member is the same if it is a standard layout class.  There is also a dupe about that.

Comment: Maybe duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254605/is-a-structs-address-the-same-as-its-first-members-address

Comment: What about using `__attribute__((packed))` ? So you know for sure there is no padding ? It might be wrong, just an idea.

Comment: I'm curious - when is it useful to know 'the address of the first element regardless of what that element is', as distinct from 'the address of the struct'?

Comment: @NathanOliver `offsetof` doesn't help cause I need to use the name of the element. And I need to do this without knowing the first element's name.

Comment: Do you know the type of the first member?

Comment: Why do you need this? Maybe this is an X-Y-question or someone gets an idea after you describe the use case

Comment: @NathanOliver Hmmm... I do not. That's going to be a problem. Even if I find the pointer, I can only use this as a `void*` it's not like I'm getting the actual type out :(

Comment: If you don't know it's type, or it's name, there really isn't anything you can do until reflection makes into into the standard.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm assuming that even if I did get the first address I wouldn't be able to find the type of that element?

Comment: @JonathanMee You would not.  `&name_of_struct` will give you the address to the first member, but t has the type of `decltype(name_of_struct)*`.  There isn't a way to get the type of the the member from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't think it's legal to reinterpret_cast into the 1st element of a struct is it?

It *is* legal, but only with the precondition that the class is standard-layout. Standard draft:

> [basic.compound]
>
> Two objects a and b are pointer-interconvertible if:
>
> ...
>
> - one is a standard-layout class object and the other is the first non-static data member of that object,
>     or, if the object has no non-static data members, any base class subobject of that object (10.3), or
>
> ...
>
> If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same address, and it is possible to obtain a
>   pointer to one from a pointer to the other via a reinterpret_cast  ...

Comment: So this is what I need but sadly I really need to be able to get the type as well :( That's out of scope for this question. I'll write another question at some point.

Comment: @JonathanMee To get the type of first member in general, you need (static) reflection, which is not in C++ indeed. If you can constrain the type, then you could use a trait template with an alias to the type of first member.